# Skoda Fabia 2005: what I need to know to buy a diagnostics machine?

Tags: diagnostics, skoda

I'd like to buy a diagnostics machine for my Skoda Fabia 2005. My issue is I'm absolutely newbie on this. I don't know which cable connection requires, if there's some standard, ...

Will you provide me some insights on what I need to know to buy a diagnostics machine for my car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is OBD II (On board Diagnostics), which you find in most cars since 1996.

I have a Skoda Fabia 2006, and I use a bluetooth module ([this one, but which ever will do](http://www.elm327.net/Super-Mini-ELM327.html))that I then connect to an app in my android phone to read/clear error codes, and monitor different sensor readings.

Here is a list of [Bluetooth adapters](http://mycarneedsthis.com/best-bluetooth-obd2-scan-adapters/)

You find the OBD connector right in front of your left knee, there is a little drawer, open it then continue pushing it down in the same direction, which will sound like braking it but it is normal, until you see a connector that looks like an old SCART tv. that is your OBD.