# Where's the temperature sensor on Skoda Fabia 2005?

Tags: sensor, temperature, skoda

I've already bought a diagnostics machine based on this other Q&A [Skoda Fabia 2005: what I need to know to buy a diagnostics machine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44609/skoda-fabia-2005-what-i-need-to-know-to-buy-a-diagnostics-machin)

The whole diagnostic machine has provided me OBDII P0118 ***P0118*** - Engine Coolant Temperature Sensor Circuit High Input.

Now I'd like to know where's the temperature sensor on my Skoda Fabia 2005 (TDI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 1.9TDI PD, on the right-hand side of the engine, tucked away, facing the back of the engine bay and with the socket release catch facing away from you! But only look after your temp sensor whene your engine is cold

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkwJi.]jpg

Comment: Is this engine temp sensor location or cabin temp sensor. I've been looking for the cabin temp sensor to troubleshoot my AC.